# Contact form 7 version 5.2

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have recently updated my contact form 7 plugin to version 5.7.2. Everything is working fine but one thing.

I have a form with 4 fields and a privacy checkbox below. All fields are mandatory. When I click on privacy checkbox without entering anything in above 4 inputs, an error message is displayed.

I want to remove those validations. I want to only display errors when the user clicks on the submit button, not on the lost focus of inputs or the checking of box.
I was unable to find a solution.

Can anyone help me here?

This is the link to check this issue - https://sawstg.wpengine.com/contact-us/

I tried to remove the error spans with jquery when the checkbox is clicked, but its not working

Comment: This is a bug with latest versions of Contact Form 7. I started a thread about it [here][1] but no fix has been released yet. 






  [1]: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/validation-issue-when-checking-checkbox-fields/page/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to include the following script on your website. This will prevent the validation event from triggering when clicking on a checkbox.

```
$('.wpcf7 input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Shaun. It worked. But the same thing is happening with textboxes and textarea too.
I tried the same code with focusout but its not working.

My code below:

$('.wpcf7 input[type="text"]').on("focusout", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.wpcf7 textarea]').on("focusout", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});